# Is there a thread safe way to get a callstack of the current thread in c/c++ on Windows?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

I have been trying to get a callstack of the current thread to improve an existing tracing library used in our library code. I want to have file and line numbers or at the very least function/method name, just raw adresses will not do.

The problem I have is that StackWalker and other solutions based on dbghelp.h functions are not thread safe, and I randomly get crashes when using StackWalker even if I use a mutex inside my library. I also tried to use boost::stacktrace, but it would not work and boost is very unpopular in my organisation.

My goal is at first to make it work on Windows, then I would work on a linux/posix implementation which will probably be much easier. I'm not very knowledgable about win32 api, does any of you know of any Api to achive this? In the end, I'd like to make everything open source. I'd also like to make this library dead simple and small, so that anybody can use it.

Thanks!

Comment: There's little use in producing a stack trace on Windows, where you have much more powerful tools, like [MiniDumpWriteDump](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/minidumpapiset/nf-minidumpapiset-minidumpwritedump). In fact, that's your only hope of getting symbol information, without actually shipping symbols with your application.

Comment: get call stack of **current** thread is **always** thread safe, because accessed data  which belong to current thread only. `StackWalk[64]` designed for debuggers - for do this for another process, thread. for do this for self thread - use [`RtlCaptureStackBackTrace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/nf-winnt-rtlcapturestackbacktrace)

Comment: *I want to have file and line numbers* - for this you need *pdb*. as variant you can save info from `CV_INFO_PDB` (look for `IMAGE_DEBUG_DIRECTORY` with `IMAGE_DEBUG_TYPE_CODEVIEW`) if your binary have debug info and latter convert this to file and line numbers where you have corresponded pdb

Comment: I looked into boost in more detail. It worked with multiple threads, and it does not seams to use dbghelp.h functions. They use functions from Dbgeng.h, and those functions do not have the remark that they are not thread safe. Also, stepping into boost stacktrace code, I do not see any locking. I think I will look into the boost implementation, and try to come up with something similar.

Comment: @nicolasb565 - *Dbgeng.h* you need if you implement debugger and/or do this for another process (not self). if you want do this for self thread - most simply and efficient way use *RtlCaptureStackBackTrace*. for get file/line number from address - you need have pdb file